# Как заменить элемент в listBox на введенный в текстовое поле и обновить listBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Как заменить элемент в listBox на введенный в текстовое поле и обновить listBox?

```
ICollectionView myDataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listBox1.Items);

using (myDataView.DeferRefresh())
{
    myDataView.Refresh();
}
```

Пытаюсь обновить представление, но получаю ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный кусок кода заменяет в ListBox значение на введенное с текстового поля. Обновляет само все:

```
  int i = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    listBox1.Items.Insert(i, textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: `listBox1.Items[i] = textBox1.Text;`

разве не поможет?

Comment: Удаляет первый элемент в listBoxe и получаю пустое значение.

    int i = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    listBox1.Items.Insert(i, textBox1.Text);

Comment: listBox1.Items[i] = textBox1.Text; 
И этот код делает тоже самое.

Comment: Удаляет первый элемент делает его пустым а новый элемент вставляет 2